# App store approval process for apps that need environment setup

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am submitting an app to the App Store that interacts with a server component that each customer who buys the app has installed.

Is it appropriate to send Apple the server component and instructions for setting it up? Or should we give Apple a test account that is directed to a test server that we host.

Thanks.

Comment: A test account pointed to a test server is likely the better solution for Apple - remember to place all required info and instructions in the review notes section :)

Comment: Like Luke pointed out, they won't set up that component in order to reproduce your expected behaviour. That would take too much time. A test account and the instructions will be enough for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution was to setup a test account for Apple.

Answer (score 0):

**You should always support everything your application does**, so Apple can fully test it. You should also keep it simple and short: usually just the credentials so they just can login and probably some instructions if you think its necessary. This assumes that a fully testing environment should be ready for them.